# Pandas Multiindex Series Processing

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I have a pandas 2 index series that I got from `a.groupby()` on my original DataFrame:

```
label  ncsc
False  0       297
       1       537
       2       333
       3       207
       4        51
       5        12
       6         4
       7         2
True   0        29
       1        68
       2        35
       3        29
       4        35
       5        18
       6         8
       7         2
Name: ncsc, dtype: int64
```

I would like to be able to compute for each `'ncsc'` the True rate, ie, for 'ncsc'=6, True rate = 8/(4+8) = 0.66.
Do you see a way to do that without using a loop but with a 'pandas syntax'?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pretend you work with numbers:

```
s[True] / (s[True] + s[False])
#0    0.088957
#1    0.112397
#2    0.095109
#3    0.122881
#4    0.406977
#5    0.600000
#6    0.666667
#7    0.500000
```

Comment: definitely the best solution. pandas indexes are really beautiful

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
f = lambda s,v: s[s.index.get_level_values(0) == v].to_frame().reset_index('index', drop=True)

tru = f(s, True)
fal = f(s, False)
(tru)/(tru+fal)

      ncsc
label   
0     0.088957
1     0.112397
2     0.095109
3     0.122881
4     0.406977
5     0.600000
6     0.666667
7     0.500000
```